# Show duplicated data comparing two different columns

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an issue and trying to resolve it. Basically what I need to do is to compare two separate columns and see if there are some duplicates, then create separate column that will show this particular data.

Please note that this formula will need to validate different sort of symbols. I attached temple how it supposed to look like.

[image: template]

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged both Google sheets and Excel I'll reply for an Excel solution. Note that Google sheets and Excel aren't the same:

`=FILTER(A2:A6,ISNUMBER(XMATCH(A2:A6,B2:B6)))`

Comment: `^1`. I think `COUNTIFS()` would better instead of `isnumber/xmatch` like `=FILTER(A2:A6,COUNTIFS(A2:A6,B2:B6))`.

Comment: I think it's better understandable, but slower